# Editable notes function button not functioning in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, button, append

The jquery code to allow a form and button to show entered data as a list is not functioning. The code is also written to delete the text when it is clicked on - unable to check if this is also working. Any suggestions on where the error may be found?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
        $('.list').append("<div class='item'>" + toAdd + "</div>");
    });
    $('.list').click(function(){      
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

html

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
   <!-- <script src="js_lib/jquery-ui.js"></script>-->  
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

    <title>A Simple Notes List</title>
  
<h1><span>A Simple Notes List</span></h1>

<div id="canvas" class="container group">
    
    <div id="primaryContent" class="group">
       <p> </p>

        <form name="checkListForm">
            <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
        </form>
        <div id="button" value="button">Add!</div>
        <br/>
        <div class="list"></div>

        <p>Click item on list to remove item from list</p>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: What error? Worked fine to remove the Element when I tested it. You should put all your code inside your `.ready(function(){ /* in here */ })`, as a best practice though.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Will put code inside function as you recommended going forwards. However, for some reason the code isn't working for me. The button has no effect when I click it. I have tried on several browsers and unsure why it isn't working.

Comment: You button needs an `id='button'` for that code to work.

Comment: what does the html look like?

Comment: Edited to add html - id='button is present in div but code is still not functional for me

Comment: I figured it out, had some unnecessary div elements in my html. It's working now, thanks!